# Apply a discount from second product with Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I simply need **to add a 10% discount to every product in the cart starting from the second one.**

I tried many discount plugins but none of them suits my customer's needs.

I.e. I need this scenario:

**Variable product 1** - *€ 100*
**Variable product 2** - *€ 200*
**Variable product 3** - *€ 300*

**Case 1**

User buys **product 2** 
He pays *€ 100*

**Case 2**

User buys product 3
He pays € 300

**Case 3 (with discount)**

User buys **product 3 and product 1**
He pays *€ 390* 
(10% discount *calculated on lowest price*)

**Case 4 (with discount)**

User buys **product 3 and product 2**
He pays *€ 480*
(10% discount *calculated on lowest price*)

**Case 5 (with discount)**
User buys **products 3,2,1**
He pays *€ 570*
(10% discount *calculated on product 2 and 1*)

Is it possible to create such a system?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
function add_discount_price_percent( $cart_object ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $custom_discount_per = 10; // custom discount percent
    $pdtcnt=0;

    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        $pdtcnt++;
        if($pdtcnt>1) { // from second product
            $oldprice = $cart_item['data']->price; //original product price
            $newprice = $oldprice - ($oldprice*($custom_discount_per/100)); //discounted price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($newprice);
        }        
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_discount_price_percent' );
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't ask for a complete solution or a code but it's obviously appreciated and it does works perfectly, moreover. 

I tried numerous discounts plugin, bought two and tried a solution by myself but I'm not skilled with WC APIs so I didn't managed how to do it.